# Android package location in Android Studio

Tags: android, directory, package

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

I studied the directory structure in Android studio, its got the app (root directory), src directory (which has main and res directories), so the java directory should have the java packages.Where are the above listed Android packages coming from ?res directory I heard has non java files.(like xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer to quick beginner

This all classes coming from **android.jar** (The platform that you selected for your project) and these all are `.class files` (Byte code only). You can't modify it.

### Screen Shot

[image]